# Set all convergent sequence in N is countable???

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused how to think or start , i know that any sequnece of Natural numbers is convergent if it is  eventually constant , this set is infinite , but how to know whether it is counatable or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, if a sequence $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ converges, it must be stationary i.e it has to be constant from some point onwards.

How many all possible finite sequences can you make? For a given $n\in\mathbb N$ your finite sequences live in
$$\underbrace{\mathbb N\times\ldots\times\mathbb N}_{n\text{ copies}} $$
That is a countable set. Now, collect them all inside
$$\bigcup _{n\in\mathbb N}\prod _{k=1}^n \mathbb N $$
This is countable because a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Since you have countably infinitely many finite sequences, you have countably many ways of completing every finite sequence to a convergent sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: what is a finite sequence ? domain of sequence is Natural number so it is infinite , iam not getting it .

Comment: A finite sequence is an $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots , a_n)$. We can complete this to a sequence by declaring $a_{n+1} = a_{n+2} = \ldots$ because we know we want to describe a converging sequence. The only question is, how many $n$-tuples can we obtain: the answer, countably infinitely many.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Set up a bijection between eventually constant sequences and finite sequences (of length $\geq 0$), then count all the finite sequences.

Comment: can you briefly explain ? iam new to this

Comment: what do you mean by finite sequences (here )?

Comment: @user534210 I mean a sequence which has a finite number of terms, like $1, 2, 3, 4$, as opposed to an infinite sequence like $1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4,\ldots$. And the reason I suggest this is that it's a bit more obvious how to count finite sequences than to count converging (infinite) sequences, even though ultimately it's the basically same process.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry to awaken an old thread, but I was about to post this exact question. I was wondering, what would be the domain and codomain of this bijective map?

Comment: @MB Since it's a bijection, it doesn't rally matter which is the domain and which is the codomain, but one of the two sets in question is the set of infinite sequences that from some point on are constant (i.e. repeating the same number over and over). The other is the set of finite length sequences. If we let the set of finite sequences be the domain, then one possible bijection is to just take the final element and repeat it infinitely. The inverse map would be to take a sequence that is eventually just repeating the same number over and over, and just chop off all that repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for gaining intuition: decimal representation of fractions. What do the *eventually constant" sequences represent? Is this a countable set?

Can you define some sort order and list (eventually) *all* these sequences by that order?